# Is there lesser or no tax on assets?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I was reading online and a link said that doctors in US give around 50% of their earnings in tax while the author gives 0% because he makes money from assets. Is it that there is no or very less taxation on assets?
Example: It is said Warren Buffet pays lesser tax than his secretary. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: There is no federal tax on assets.  (There are local property taxes on real estates and things like that.)  If you have billions of dollars under your mattress but received no income this year, you don't owe anything in taxes this year.  However, if you earn income from your assets (interest, dividends, rent, etc), or you sell some of your assets for more than you paid for them, you will usually owe tax on that income.

Comment: (@Nate) but much investment income _is_ subject to _lower rates_ -- specifically 'long term' capital gains (over a year) and 'qualified' dividends (roughly, those from US stock you hold at least 3 months). For people who would be in the 15% bracket on 'ordinary' income, LTCG/QD rate is _zero_. Plus the taxes on 'earned' income (FICA/SECA) do not apply to investment income. (Although most doctors have income over the 'cap' for Social Security tax, so their effective rate is _reduced somewhat_ but not to zero.) Also OP: Buffett is a man, so 'his' secretary.

Answer (score 1):

US federal tax law distinguishes many types of income. For most people, most of their income is "earned income", money you were paid to do a job. Another category of income is "capital gains", money you made from the sale of an asset.

For a variety of reasons, capital gains tax rates are lower than earned income tax rates. (For example, it is common that much of the gain is not real profit but inflation. If you buy an asset for $10,000 and sell it for $15,000, you pay capital gains tax on the $5,000 profit. But what if prices in general since you bought the asset have gone up 50%? Then your entire profit is really inflation, you didn't actually make any money -- but you still have to pay a tax on the paper gain.)

So if you make your money by investing in assets -- buying and selling at a profit -- you will pay lower taxes than if you made the same amount of money by receiving a salary from a job, or by running a business where you sell your time and expertise rather than an asset.

But money made from assets -- capital gains -- is not tax free. It's just a lower tax. It MIGHT be that when combined with other deductions and tax credits this would result in you paying no taxes in a particular year. Maybe you could avoid paying taxes forever if you can take advantage of tax loopholes. But for most people, making money from capital gains could result in lower taxes per dollar of income than someone doing more ordinary work. Or it could result in higher taxes, if you factor in inflation, net present value of money, and so on.

BTW Warren Buffet's "secretary" is not a typist. She apparently makes at least $200,000 a year. http://www.forbes.com/sites/paulroderickgregory/2012/01/25/warren-buffetts-secretary-likely-makes-between-200000-and-500000year/#ab91f3718b8a. And side note: if Warren Buffet thinks he isn't paying enough in taxes, why doesn't he voluntarily pay more? The government has a web site where citizens can voluntarily pay additional taxes. In 2015 they received $3.9 million in such contributions. http://www.treasurydirect.gov/govt/reports/pd/gift/gift.htm

Answer (score 0):

[Tax Shield](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/taxshield.asp) would be known as:

> A tax shield is a reduction in taxable income for an individual or
>   corporation achieved through claiming allowable deductions such as
>   mortgage interest, medical expenses, charitable donations,
>   amortization and depreciation. These deductions reduce a taxpayer's
>   taxable income for a given year or defer income taxes into future
>   years. Tax shields lower the overall amount of taxes owed by an
>   individual taxpayer or a business.

I know of various real estate investors that will use depreciation as noted above to reduce their tax liability though others can use other deductions.

[Fortune](http://fortune.com/2016/10/10/warren-buffett-taxes-trump/) has this on Buffett's taxes in 2015:

> Here’s the breakdown of Buffett’s income taxes for 2015, according to
>   the statement:
>
> ```
> Adjusted gross income: $11.6 million
> Deductible charitable contributions: $3.5 million
> Total deductions: $5.5 million
> Federal income tax paid: $1.8 million
> ```